# Не работает функция gets() В первый раз она не работает но во второй раз работает

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct car_info {
    char brand[20];
    char model[20];
    int release_year;
    float engine_capacity;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    char first_sort_filter, second_sort_filter;

    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    struct car_info *car;

    car = malloc(sizeof(struct car_info) * n);

    gets(car->brand);
    gets(car->model);
    scanf_s("%d", &car->release_year);
    scanf_s("%f", &car->engine_capacity);

    printf("1%s", car->brand);
    printf("2%s", car->model);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если ввод первого `scanf_s("%d", &n);` завершить нажатием <Enter>, то символ `\n` (до появления которого `gets` читает символы) остается во входном потоке ввода. Вот до него-то (т.е. скорее всего пустую строку) и читает `gets(car->brand);` / Напишите простую функцию `int skip_nl()` и вызывайте ее после последовательности scanf-ов перед gets-ом

Comment: Вообще опасный код. А что, если пользователь введёт больше, чем 19 символов? Тогда произойдёт переполнение буфера! По-этому лучше использовать `fgets()`.

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Решение найдено нужно сбросить буфер ввода
       ' **scanf_s("%*[^\n]");
 scanf_s("%*c");**'